# MSB 1009 : project File doesn't exist

Tags: jenkins, cmake, msbuild, jenkins-pipeline

Terminal is given as:

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Pipeline1>cmake . .
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

    C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.2+25e4d540b for .NET Framework
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
    Switch: VCTargetsPath.vcxproj


  Exit code: 1



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Windows/System32/config/systemprofile/AppData/Local/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/Pipeline1/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I have declared MSBuild path in system variables and I have VisualStudio 16 2019 version.